# How does one create a lean project even if it already exists e.g., lake +leanprover/lean4:nightly-2023-02-04 new my_project math?

Tags: lean, lean4, lean-community

I want to initialize a lean project but **the folder I have already exists**. How do I do this?

e.g.,

```bash
# -- Go to a folder where you want to create a project in a subfolder my_project, and type lake +leanprover/lean4:nightly-2023-02-04 new my_project math.
cd $HOME
lake +leanprover/lean4:nightly-2023-02-04 new my_project math
```

but I get the following error

```bash
~ ❯ mkdir my_project
mkdir: my_project: File exist
```

I do not want to alter the contents or move `my_project`, but have the `lake` command do whatever it needs to do even if the folder exists. I do not want to move the contents out of my_project etc. Just that `lake +leanprover/lean4:nightly-2023-02-04 new my_project math` works even if the folder exists.

Comment: Change `my_project` to any name you want that doesn't match an existing directory.

Comment: What do you want to happen if `my_project` contains files whose names are the same as project system files which `lake` wants to create as part of the process of creating a new project? What do you want to happen if `my_project` is already a git repo? My instinct is that you should solve these questions yourself by renaming `my_project` to `foo`, using `lake` to create `my_project` and then copying the files from `foo` back into `my_project`, being very careful if there are any name clashes.